# Java App Engine Project in eclipse return Server App Engine Standard at Localhost failed to start

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin, google-app-engine-launch

I'm working on a Java App Engine application using Java 7 in Eclipse Photon. I have an existed App engine Java web application received from one of our developers when I create a new App engine standard project and import this project and try to run it return this error:

> Server App Engine Standard at localhost failed to start.

And Here's the stack trace:

```
Warning: Google App Engine Java 7 runtime is deprecated.
Warning: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create a DevAppServer
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:401)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:31)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:318)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:315)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:314)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:374)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:238)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ClassLoader is jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4459eb14, not a URLClassLoader.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller.generatePolicyFile(SecurityManagerInstaller.java:139)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller.install(SecurityManagerInstaller.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:377)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2464..Try checking in the link i've shared...

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, in my case even Helloworld app is getting the same error.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/

Comment: @AbdulRehman Please confirm whether or not you were following [this](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart) quickstart. Check [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264254/appengine-maven-plugin1-3-1-run-failed-non-zero-exit) and if the issue still persist please provide your `pom.xml` but delete all sensitive info like you Google Cloud Project ID.

Answer (score 1):

So your stack trace indicates that you are launching with a Java 9 VM (or later), which isn't supported the App Engine development tools.

```
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Assuming you're using the Cloud Tools for Eclipse, first ensure your Google Cloud SDK is up-to-date.  If you're using your own copy, run `gcloud components update` on the command-line.  If you're letting Cloud Tools for Eclipse manage your SDK, then open *Preferences > Google Cloud Tools* and choose *Update*.

You'll then need to configure Eclipse to use a Java 8 JRE or JDK as the default JVM for Java 8 launches:

1. Install a Java 8 VM if you don't have one already.
2. Open *Preferences > Java > Installed JREs*.  Choose *Add* or *Search* if your Java 8 VM is not found.
3. Open *Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments* and select `JavaSE-1.8`, and ensure that your Java 8 VM is checked as the default VM.

(You can repeat the above if you're using a Java 1.7 VM, though note that [App Engine support for Java 7 will be turned off in January 2019](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7).)

You should then be able to launch.